# Missing /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo

Tags: debian, suspend, brightness, graphic-card

I have recently bought a `Dell Inspiron 5567` and I have installed Debian 8 on it.

First of all my wireless was not working so I had to update my **linux kernel** to **4.1** and copy some `iwlwifi` firmware from the internet into my `/sys/firmware` folder to successfully connect to any wifi.

Then I noticed that I could not use my brightness keys and Gnome3 was not giving me a slider to set the brightness either (I can set the brightness from BIOS though). Also, suspend does not work either. If I close my laptop lid I get a black screen with a flashy underscore (just like a terminal window) and I have to shut down my laptop using the power button.

I've done some checks and realised that my laptop is not using the dedicated graphics card that I have, but the integrated one.

The output of `lspci` is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 1903 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d2f (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d31 (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d60 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d61 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3a (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d03 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d14 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d15 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d58 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d21 (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9d23 (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] (rev c3)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 3165 (rev 79)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

So I looked online and found [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) article which tells you how to switch between GPUs.

The problem is I do not have `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo` and my BIOS is not giving me an option to change my active GPU.

How can I fix the missing `vgaswitcheroo` folder or how can I switch to my radeon graphics card?

Also, would this help me solve my brightness and suspend problems? That is the reason why I am doing all of this.